# Pandas to modify values in csv file based on function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file that looks like below, this is same like my last question but this is by using Pandas.

```
Group   Sam         Dan         Bori    Son     John    Mave
A       0.00258844  0.983322    1.61479 1.2785  1.96963 10.6945
B       0.0026034   0.983305    1.61198 1.26239 1.9742  10.6838
C       0.0026174   0.983294    1.60913 1.24543 1.97877 10.6729
D       0.00263062  0.983289    1.60624 1.22758 1.98334 10.6618
E       0.00264304  0.98329     1.60332 1.20885 1.98791 10.6505
```

I have a function like below

```
def getnewno(value):
    value = value + 30
    if value > 40 :
        value = value - 20
    else:
        value = value
    return value
```

I want to send all these `values` to the  `getnewno` function and get a `newvalue` and update the CSV file. How can this be accomplished in Pandas.

**Expected output:**

```
Group   Sam         Dan         Bori        Son         John        Mave
A       30.00258844 30.983322   31.61479    31.2785     31.96963    20.6945
B       30.0026034  30.983305   31.61198    31.26239    31.9742     20.6838
C       30.0026174  30.983294   31.60913    31.24543    31.97877    20.6729
D       30.00263062 30.983289   31.60624    31.22758    31.98334    20.6618
E       30.00264304 30.98329    31.60332    31.20885    31.98791    20.6505
```

Comment: kindly post how the new dataframe would look

Comment: using the DataFrame.apply() method and then the DataFrame.to_csv() method will work here.

Comment: @Wade can you please give me an example

Comment: @sammywemmy added `Expected Output`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should give you what you desire.

#### Applying a function

Your function can be simplified and here expressed as a `lambda` function.

It's then a matter of applying your function to all of the columns. There are a number of ways to do so. The first idea that comes to mind is to loop over `df.columns`. However, we can do better than this by using the `applymap` or `transform` methods:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read in the data from file
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',
                 sep='\s+',
                 index_col=0)

# Simplified function with which to transform data
getnewno = lambda value: value + 10 if value > 10 else value + 30

# Looping over columns
#for col in df.columns:
#    df[col] = df[col].apply(getnewno)

# Apply to all columns without loop
df = df.applymap(getnewno)

# Write out updated data
df.to_csv('data_updated.csv')
```

#### Using broadcasting

You can achieve your result using broadcasting and a little boolean logic. This avoids looping over any columns, and should ultimately prove faster and less memory intensive (although if your dataset is small any speed-up would be negligible):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',
                 sep='\s+',
                 index_col=0)

df += 30
make_smaller = df > 40
df[make_smaller] -= 20
```

Comment: This works, thank you, i was looking for `for col in df.columns` , its been a while since i used `pandas`. thanks for your efforts. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `getnewno` function looks too complicated... it can be simplified to e.g.:

```
def getnewno(value):
    if value + 30 > 40:
        return value - 20
    else:
        return value
```

you can even change `value + 30 > 40` to `value > 10`.

Or even a oneliner if you want:

```
getnewno = lambda value: value-20 if value > 10 else value
```

Having the function you can apply it to specific values/columns. For example, if want you to create a column `Mark_updated` basing on `Mark` column, it should look like this (I assume your pandas DataFrame is called `df`):

```
df['Mark_updated'] = df['Mark'].apply(getnewno)
```

Comment: as i mentioned in the question, i want all the `columns` to go through this `function` and get a new value. is there a `for each` kind of thing in `pandas` that can do this?

Comment: for all columns apply the function for whole DF: `df2 = df.apply(getnewno)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [mask](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) function to do an if-else solution, before writing the data to csv

```
res = (df
 .select_dtypes('number')
 .add(30)
 #the if-else comes in here
 #if any entry in the dataframe is greater than 40, subtract 20 from it
 #else leave as is
 .mask(lambda x: x>40, lambda x: x.sub(20))
)
#insert the group column back
res.insert(0,'Group',df.Group.array)
```

write to csv

```
res.to_csv(filename)


    Group   Sam       Dan         Bori       Son        John       Mave
0   A   30.002588   30.983322   31.61479    31.27850    31.96963    20.6945
1   B   30.002603   30.983305   31.61198    31.26239    31.97420    20.6838
2   C   30.002617   30.983294   31.60913    31.24543    31.97877    20.6729
3   D   30.002631   30.983289   31.60624    31.22758    31.98334    20.6618
4   E   30.002643   30.983290   31.60332    31.20885    31.98791    20.6505
```